# Analytic approach for computing expected maximum value of subset

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I have a set of $n$ real numbers $X=\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}\in [0, 1]$.

**Question:** Is there a nice (analytic) way to compute $\mathbb{E}(\max(\{x_{i_1},...,x_{i_k}\}))$ where $\{x_{i_1},...,x_{i_k}\}$ is a size $k$ subset of $X$ chosen uniformly at random?  I would be interested in an answer in the case when all the values are distinct, and in the case when some values are repeated.  In the actual data I have, the value $0$ is repeated a number of times but the rest are distinct.

**My Solution:** The obvious way to approximate the expected maximum value is to just randomly sample a few thousand $k$ element subsets, compute the maximum value, and take an average.  This is the approach I will take if I cannot find a good "analytical" approach.

The analytic solution is also easy if $k=1$ or if $k=n$.  If $k=1$ then the expected maximum value is the same as the mean of the set (since max of a single element is just that element).  If $k=n$ then it is just the maximum value $X$.  Furthermore, it is clear that this function $f(k) = \mathbb{E}(\max(\{x_{i_1},...,x_{i_k}\}))$ is increasing.

Comment: The $x_i$'s do not come from any known distribution.  They are values of a black box function that I've queried at $n$ different random points.  My goal is to find the max value of the function (randomly) and I want to estimate how well I can "estimate" the maximum value by randomly querying the function $k$ times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality, you can rewrite the numbers in relative order so that the smallest is $x_1$ and the largest is $x_n$. This is because you'll be choosing these numbers uniformly at random, hence all permutations occur with equal probability. Assuming the numbers are distinct,

$$P(\max(x_{i_1},\cdots,x_{i_k})=z=x_r)=\frac{\binom{r-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k}}.$$

The numerator is calculated as follows. We require $x_r$ to be picked, and every other number must occur to the left of $x_r$, giving $r-1$ choices. Clearly if $r-1<k$ then the probability is 0.

Thus

$$E[\max(x_{i_1},\cdots,x_{i_k})]=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{\binom{r-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k}}x_r.$$

Comment: This is remarkably nice; I'm ashamed to admit how much time I spent trying to do this.  Ordering the $x_i$ so that $x_i\leq x_{i+1}$ was a great insight.  It seems to me like there might be a typo.  Should the numerator be $\binom{r-1}{k-1}$?

Comment: @TravisJ: Yep you're right. Thanks!